# JavaScript closures and methods

Tags: javascript, closures

In the following case:

```
var o1 = {}
var o2 = {}

o1.a = function a() {}
o2.b = function b() {
  o1.a()
}
```

Does `o2.b` "close over" `o1`, or just the reference to the `o1.a` function?

I doubt this has a major affect on performance or memory, especially considering that we do this all the time with the global scope, but I'm just curious.

Answer (score -1):

Just the reference. That particular call will have access to `o2.b()`'s scope, but if you call `o1.a()` somewhere else it will also have access to the scope of whatever you put it in at the time (global or closure).